# How to solve the trigonometric equation $\cos (\pi\theta/\beta) - \cos(2\pi\theta/\beta)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I have a question regarding a problem I've been attempting to solve. It is an acceleration equation:

$$a = \frac{1}{2}H\left(\frac{\pi\omega}{\beta}\right)^2\left[\cos\left(\frac{\pi\theta}{\beta}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi\theta}{\beta}\right)\right]$$

Assuming all variables are set constant except for theta, and that theta can take on any value such that  $ 0 \le \theta \le \beta $.

Assuming $H$ and $\beta$ are not zero, what values of theta would cause the acceleration to equal zero? I understand that theta with a value of of zero would cause the acceleration to be zero but there is one more. Graphical representation shows this, but how would I algebraically solve for this second value? I'm stumped.. The graph is on the very right.

[image]

Comment: are the values of $\theta$ and $\beta$ upper bounded?

Comment: \beta can be whatever it wants. However, \theta can only be from 0 to \beta. \beta is the maximum distance to be traveled, and \theta is the current position.

Comment: so $\beta$ can be, say, $18\pi$?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use $\cos(2x) = 2\cos^2(x)-1$, you get a quadratic in terms of $\cos(\pi\theta/\beta)$. Then you can take the roots of the quadratic to find values for $\cos(\pi\theta/\beta)$, and solve for $\theta$.

Comment: Doesn't that miss $cos(-\theta) = cos(\theta)$ ?

Comment: ...nope. You get 1 and -1/2 as values for the cosine. Then -1/2 gives you two opposite values for theta.

Comment: Of course. The cosine identity is applied after the solution to the quadratic.

Comment: And then of course, you exclude the one case in the three you get that doesn't match the criteria.

Comment: So I just followed this advice and got the correct answer. I'm curious though, were you able to realize this simply from your experience with trig identities? I don't know how I could have found that myself.

Comment: You could say I know from experience to use the double angle formula anytime I see cos x and cos 2x in the same expression, because otherwise there's no way to relate them. After that it's just solving.